# Extract specific link from the Current Page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

i want to extract a specific link content from html page (MP3 file url) to clipboard with a simple Google chrome extension, the page contains only a single mp3 url, I hope someone could help me, Thank you in advance!

This part is hidden in the Pageweb source:

```
<source src="http://url/file.mp3" type="video/mp4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm assuming that the type will be `video/mp4` for all mp3 links. If the `<source/>` type differs you may have to alter the `querySelectorAll(...)` value.*

Hope this helps:

```js
// Get all the links from `source` tags that have the type `video/mp4`
let links = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('source[type="video/mp4"]')
).map(source => source.src);

console.log(links);
```

```html
<source src="http://url/file.mp3" type="video/mp4">
<!-- Will extract from deep source tags aswell-->
<div>
  <source src="http://url/file1.mp3" type="video/mp4">
  <div>
    <source src="http://url/file2.mp3" type="video/mp4">
  </div>
</div>
```